# Custom text in browser tag header on MVC app?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

The code below runs inside a bootstrap modal window that stays open while the user can click in the links to open related pdf docs, one in each new tab in the browser. It works as desired, except that in the tab header it displays the same "localhost" text through all the new opened tabs. I would like to have the document name displayed in the tab header instead. Is this possible? I'm using MVC, razor view and jquery.

The model contains a list with the names of the existing documents

```
@model List<string>

<ul>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      string temp = "http://localhost:50805/Documents/" + @item;
      <li><a href=@temp target="_blank">@item</a></li>
   }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the page/document that gets loaded determines what is in the tab title. This cannot be set from another tab using JavaScript.

The only way I can think to work around this is by creating a document on your website that has an `iframe` which takes up all or the majority of the page. Let's say your document is called `index.cshtml` and it's in the `Preview` controller. You can call the page and use a URL parameter to pass in the target document URL:

```
@Html.ActiveLink(URLVariable , "Index", "Preview", new { target = URLVariable })
```

Then in your controller, you pass that `target` value through to the cshtml page and use it in the iframe

```
<iframe src="@target"></iframe>
```

Then from within the page you can set the `title` text of the document to whatever you want with variables or JavaScript.